# How to search for a variable and display the next variable in the list in tcl

Tags: tcl

Hi I want to search a variable in a list and display the next item in the list. Like 
If I have a list with **" aaa bbb ccc eee fff"** I want to search for **bbb** and display the next one in the list which is in this case **ccc**. I know we have to use lsearch and find the variable and use lindex to display the next one but I dont know how to move to the next variable.

Comment: If you know that you have an even list and only search for odd elements, you have a [`dict`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dict.htm). In this case you can simply use `dict get $var bbb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution which takes into account the edge cases and returns an empty string if the searched element does not satisfy the conditions:

```
proc get_item {mylist element option} {

    set i [lsearch $mylist $element]

    if {$i > -1} {
        if {$option == "previous" && $i > 0} {          
            return [lindex $mylist $i-1]
        } elseif {$option == "next" && $i >= 0 && $i < [llength $mylist] - 2} {
            return [lindex $mylist $i+1]
        }
    }

    return ""
}

set a {aaa bbb ccc ddd}
get_item $a bbb next
get_item $a bbb previous
```

Comment: The latter `> 0` should be `>= 0`. It would be a good idea to separate the code and first do an `if` to see if the element was found, then check if the element has a next or previous element. You're trying to do too much at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

```
set l {aaa bbb ccc eee fff}

set index [lsearch $l bbb]
incr index
set required [lindex $l $index]
```

It puts `ccc` into the variable `required`.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I was unsure about the lsearch option and how it works hence could not figure it out. Thank you so much. For the same code if I need to display aaa after searching for bbb then what should I do?? There is no option for decrements in tcl. @nurdglaw

Comment: @user2533429, `incr index -1`. Also, all the built-in Tcl commands are documented here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm